# how do I make this java awt/ swing animation work?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, thread-sleep

I'm pretty new to java coding, but i know the basic structures of how to code. I am not familiar with awt/swing, and don't know what my error is.

Background: I searched up ways to animate with java, found zetcode tutorials. 
I copy/pasted their code, and tested the program, to make sure it works. the JFrame opened, but nothing drew. Maybe this is a system compatibility error? if so, how would I fix it?

these are the two separate classes:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ThreadAnimationExample extends JFrame {

    public ThreadAnimationExample() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        add(new Board());

        setResizable(false);
        pack();

        setTitle("Star");    
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {                
                JFrame ex = new ThreadAnimationExample();
                ex.setVisible(true);                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the main class.

```
Board.java
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel
    implements Runnable {

    private final int B_WIDTH = 350;
    private final int B_HEIGHT = 350;
    private final int INITIAL_X = -40;
    private final int INITIAL_Y = -40;
    private final int DELAY = 25;

    private Image star;
    private Thread animator;
    private int x, y;

    public Board() {

        initBoard();
    }

    private void loadImage() {

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("star.png");
        star = ii.getImage();
    }

    private void initBoard() {

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT));
        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        loadImage();

        x = INITIAL_X;
        y = INITIAL_Y;
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();

        animator = new Thread(this);
        animator.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        drawStar(g);
    }

    private void drawStar(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(star, x, y, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    private void cycle() {

        x += 1;
        y += 1;

        if (y > B_HEIGHT) {

            y = INITIAL_Y;
            x = INITIAL_X;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (true) {

            cycle();
            repaint();

            timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
            sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

            if (sleep < 0) {
                sleep = 2;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, I get a blank black window. The program is supposed to draw a star.  [Here is what it is supposed to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoedu.png)

Comment: Do you have the file `star.png` in the current directory when you run the program? It tries to load this image so that it can draw it in the window.

Comment: I downloaded the file, and it shows up as star.png at the bottom of the package. however, it still doesn't work.

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Oh, i fixed the problem. The image had to be sent to the project, rather than the package, because both classes called for the image. Thank you so much <3

Comment: BTW - 1) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 2) Tip: Add @Jesper (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.